# How to delete views when it doesn't exist in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I 've create some tables and views in Postgres via pgadmin4.

I change the code in one of the view, called view A, which base on table 1 and 2. I then found out I don't need table 2 in view A so try to adjust the code, but fail due to dependency.
Then I drop cascade table 2 - success, then I try to delete view A but fail and shows "could not found specific none" (below image).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGvAq.png)

Question: How to delete view A (which shows could not found) in this situation ?

Steps tried: I have try drop view, drop view with cascade, and delete but all fail to delete the view A.

I'm pretty new to Postgres, so appreciate for your help.

Thanks.

TW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop a table with `CASCADE` and there is a view that depends on it, the view is automatically dropped too. Only pgAdmin does not know that the view has been dropped. Refresh pgAdmin's display, and the view will be gone.

Comment: Hi Albe, thanks a lot for your help, it's so easy ..... ^^